# geom_point not showing on ggmap plot

Tags: r, plot, ggmap

I am trying to plot some latitude/longitude points on a map using ggmap and geom_point. I have done it before and not had any problems but this time it simply will not show. I have tried unlisting the data, tinkering with aes(), etc and nothing has worked. The output of `point_map` is only the `Area_Map` with no points. What am I missing here?

```
# Read in data from csv files. 
bearingDat <- read.csv('bearing_Data.csv', sep = ',')

lonlatDat <- read.csv('lonlat_Data.csv', sep = ',')

# Create vectors for data. 
bearing <- c(bearingDat[1])
longitude <- c(lonlatDat[2])
latitude <- c(lonlatDat[1])

# Install necessary packages.
#install.packages("ggmap", "rworldmap")
#library(ggmap)
#library(rworldmap)


# Acquire map of area. 
Area_Map <- ggmap(get_map(location = c(175.733095424,-39.278361404),
                               zoom = 18,
                               maptype = "satellite",
                               color = "color"
)
)


point_map <- Area_Map + geom_point(data = lonlatDat, 
                                        aes(x=longitude, y=latitude),
                                        col = "red", 
                                        size = 1,
                                        alpha = 0.5,
                                        na.rm = TRUE
)

point_map
```

And here is the first 10 values for longitude and latitude, respectively.

```
1   175.4404  39.15582
2   175.4404  39.22650
3   175.4404  39.22650
4   175.4404  39.22650
5   175.4404  39.22650
6   175.4404  39.22650
7   175.4404  39.22650
8   175.4404  39.22650
9   175.4403  39.42777
10  175.4403  39.42777
```

Comment: In addition to your sign error, your code to "Create vectors for data" is bad (not that you use those in your plots). If `bearingDat` is a data frame, then `bearingDat[1]` is a one-column data frame, as is `c(bearingDat[1])`. If you want a *vector*, use `bearingDat[[1]]`. (The `c()` is pointless in both cases).

Comment: @Gregor Thank you for pointing that out. Haven't spent much time with R recently so I must have gotten some things mixed up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map is at -39.278361404 and your points at 39.15582, they are on opposite sides of the world.

If you fix one or the other, then you may see something. My gut instinct tells me at they might still be outside the scope of your zoom level.

Try using:

`calc_zoom(lon, lat, data, adjust = 0, f = 0.05)`

to get a zoom level which shows the farthest point from your original map and you should be good to go.

Comment: Ahh, I wonder if my lat/long data got jumbled up when I converted from NZTM-->UTM. Thank you.

Comment: That can happen very easily. My first Leaflet map suffered from a similar conversion problem!

Comment: I tried the calc_zoom and I get the error "Error: is.integer(adjust) is not TRUE".

Comment: That is saying that whatever you set adjust equal to, a variable or a number, it is not and integer and it is failing the data type requirements of the function. Check to be sure that your numerical data is numerical and preferably an integer. Use `str(your_data_frame)` to see. The adjustment has to be an integer...convert it as necessary.